# Will YouTube continue to support Gameshow for live streaming?

Tags: youtube, youtube-live

A few days ago, I opened up Gameshow to start a live stream. Then I came across this message:

> For the next year we will be updating Gameshow when necessary, but after January 1, 2020, there will no longer be any updates to Gameshow.

After Gameshow stops updating, will YouTube continue to support streaming from Gameshow to YouTube?

Answer (score 1):

> To get straight to the point, we are no longer making Gameshow. 
>   Starting today it will no longer be for sale, and starting in 2020 we
>   will no longer be updating it.
>
> What does this mean for you?
>
> Don’t worry you get to keep Gameshow forever.  For the next year we
>   will update it if anything comes up, but by 2020, there will be no
>   more updates.
>
> When we first made Gameshow we were excited to jump headfirst into one
>   of the most exciting communities around. We all know it is one of the
>   most amazing phenomena of the 21st century, and we still believe it
>   will grow for many years.
>
> Unfortunately, Gameshow is being discontinued due to a shift in focus
>   and investment here at Telestream.
>
> We wish you all the best in your streaming adventures and hope that
>   Gameshow continues to serve you well!
>
> **https://gameshow.forumbee.com/t/80dndm/gameshow-end-of-sales**

It's highly possible that YouTube will stop supporting it after some period of time when Gameshow will be outdated by lack of any update fixes, but there haven't been any announcements for discontinued YouTube support of Gameshow, yet. Telestream's main focus will be shifted to Wirecast.

Comment: Interesting, Anyways thank you very much!

Comment: @Google https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers